# How to solve this without using zip

Tags: python

the question is "Create a dictionary using range() as following.

`{'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'd':4,'e':5....'y':25, 'z':26}`.

The code needs to be in one line."
I can do this with using zip, but how to do it without the use of zip?

Comment: How did you do it using `zip`? Why don't you want to continue using `zip`? What's the specific problem in your current implementation you're trying to solve?

Comment: Show your attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you do it with `zip`?
I don't think it get much easier than

```py
{chr(96+i):i for i in range(1,27)}
```

Same idea, different indizes, no magic number:

```py
{chr(ord('a')+i):i+1 for i in range(26)}
```

Comment: Apologies for asking a stupid question, but what do I have to print here.

Comment: On an interactive console like IDLE you don't have to use an explicit print statement. It prints out the generated expression after every line. If you want to print a dictionary `d` from within a script you can just use `print(d)`. Or you iterate over it and print it in some fancy way. Depends on your needs.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, BRO!!